# Resistance bands

Tags: resistance-cord

I need some advice regaurding resistance bands. I am thinking of buying one of them (and only one probably). I want it to develop muscles. I am not able to perform bodyweight exercises properly as my muscles are weak (which is why I am thinking  of buying a resistance band to develop them). I need advice regaurding what type (light ,medium or heavy) band I should buy. I dont want it to be too easy. I dont have access to free weights nor to gyms. I have seen some videos on resistance band exercises and it seems to be effective. Does anybody have any opinion/experience otherwise? Please help.
Also which lenght resistance band will be ideal for me? I am 5 feet 5 inches and weight is about 60 kg.

Comment: Thank you . I have read that question and answers too but they weren't too useful

Comment: Without knowing details of your strength level or level of fitness, I would say that your best bet is to go to a sports equipment store and ask to try some out, see what band seems to give you a good workout without being too easy or too hard. Which bodyweight exercises have you tried? What muscles are you targeting?

Comment: I want to strengthen my upper ams thighs chest and stomach muscles. I have tried push ups(I can go halfway down) and pullups (in vain).

Answer (score 0):

Resistance bands can be a good way to strengthen your muscles when you are not strong enough to support your bodyweight in exercise.

The strength of the resistance band should allow you to be able to complete the motion.  If the band is too strong, you may not be able to complete the motion as you near the end of the range.  If the band is not strong enough, you will likely break it.

Generally, it is best to have more than one resistance level to accommodate the different upper and body exercises that you want to do. You will use the weaker band for weaker muscle groups. When you outgrow an easier resistance band, upgrade to a heavier band.  As the heavier band becomes too easy you can combine bands for additional resistance.

Bands are color coded to represent different weights or resistance levels.  They are often designated with a range of weight such as 5-8# or 12-16# to help you decide depending on the muscle groups you are targeting.  Detachable handles and door straps for attachments are helpful. (Our site has more information on [resistance levels](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Resistance-Bands.html) if you are interested.)

As @Sean suggests, if you have no idea what resistance levels are right for you, try some out at your local sporting goods store.  Find which ones give you the greatest versatility for both your upper and lower body.